# Android: what is the best way to update the Activity view from within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewflipper

I have a `DialogFragment` and when the user clicks "Ok" on the dialog it is dismissed and I want to re-draw the activity layout.

I am using a `viewflipper` for three layouts within the `Activity`. Do I use `getActivity()` within the fragment to access the `viewflipper` so that the layout view can be updated?

partial Activity file:

```
...
private ViewFlipper viewflipper;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);
    viewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
```

partial xml file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/cardview_nobuttons"
    android:id="@+id/cardviewNobuttons"  />

<include layout="@layout/cardview_previewbuttons"
    android:id="@+id/cardviewPreviewbuttons" />

<include layout="@layout/cardview_twobuttons"
    android:id="@+id/cardviewTwobuttons"  />

</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

partial fragment file:

```
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
...   
dismiss();
getActivity().viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(viewflipper.indexOfChild
   (findViewById(R.id.cardviewNobuttons)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits Deividi Cavarzan.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you against this approach. Fragments shouldn't directly communicate with their hosting Activity. There is an official guide talking exactly about how to approach this issue [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Also, I suggest you to take a look at EventBus pattern, which could make this communication much easier. There are two popular implementations specifically for Android:

- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Thanks I will look into the EventBus libraries.   My issue is if the user cancels the dialog from the fragment then I want to keep the Activity's current layout.  However, if the user clicks "Ok" to clear all user input then I need to update the Activity layout.  Any other ideas on how to achieve?

Comment: Read through the guide I referenced. It's pretty clear on how to communicate with the activity via the interfaces. And if you will have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you.  Why do you strongly recommend against the approach?  Is it because the fragment has its own lifecycle that could be very different from the Activity's lifecycle?

Comment: The idea behind fragments is two have an independent building blocks which can be combined and reused in different ways. When you directly refer to the hosting activity you are are tightly coupling them together. Even if you are not going to reuse the fragment, it's generally a good practice to do it the "right" way.