# what is the best way to update fragment view from activity

Tags: android

I have one fragment and that have some view element like textview buttons.

Now My problem is I have some service running background and it is checking data from server(Mysql) when these are some data it tells to Mainactivity.

Now on the basis of result I have to update fragment texeviews buttos.

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677218/refresh-a-fragment-from-its-parent-activity) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137425/how-to-update-fragment-content-from-activity-viewpager)

Comment: create a method in your fragment, and call it from Activity: `fragment.updateUI(SomeData someData);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: what is the best way to update the Activity view from within a fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967201/android-what-is-the-best-way-to-update-the-activity-view-from-within-a-fragment)

Comment: call this method in fragment ((YourActivity)getActivity()).updateDatafromActivity();

Comment: @Somesh Kumar I have tried and my textview is getting updated in Fragment but sometimes and some times it doesn't .Mostly on android 6.0.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks Somesh Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the fragment is a section of activity.

In the activity,you will get the fragment which involve.

You get the fragment ,so you can do you want to do .